# Rails SQL syntax for LEFT JOIN query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to select all notices which 1) lie within the coordinates of a map, and 2) do not have a supernotice (and therefore no active_comment_relationship in the commentrelationships table). Comments are also of class Notice.
I can't get the SQL quite right:

```
nelat = params[:NElatitude]
swlat = params[:SWlatitude]
nelng = params[:NElongitude]
swlng = params[:SWlongitude]
find_by_sql(" SELECT     *
              FROM       notices
              WHERE      latitude  < #{nelat}
              AND        latitude  > #{swlat}
              AND        longitude < #{nelng}
              AND        longitude > #{swlng}
              LEFT JOIN  commentrelationships
              ON         notices.id = commentrelationships.commenter_id
              WHERE      commentrelationships.commenter_id IS NULL
              LIMIT 50
           ; ")
```

notice.rb:

```
has_one :active_comment_relationship, class_name: "Commentrelationship",
                                      foreign_key: "commenter_id",
                                      dependent: :destroy
has_one :supernotice, through: :active_comment_relationship, source: :commentee
```

I've tried it this way round but it produces some very strange errors, I suspect because it returns Comments with the given coordinates, not Notices:

```
find_by_sql(" SELECT     *
              FROM       notices
              LEFT JOIN  commentrelationships
              ON         notices.id = commentrelationships.commenter_id
              WHERE      commentrelationships.commenter_id IS NULL
              AND        latitude  < #{nelat}
              AND        latitude  > #{swlat}
              AND        longitude < #{nelng}
              AND        longitude > #{swlng}
              LIMIT 50
           ; ")
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the rough syntax for your query. You can put these into named scopes to make it clearer if you like. It's not completely clear what your models look like, so if this does not work, add them to your question along with the exact error messages you are getting.

```
Notices.joins("LEFT JOIN commentrelationships ON commentrelationships.commenter_id = notices.id")
  .where(commenter_id: nil)
  .where('latitude < ?', nelat)
  .where('latitude > ?', swlat)
  .where('latitude < ?', nelng)
  .where('latitude > ?', swlng)
```